# What is Hooleer?

Tags: bleach

Before the Visord showed up a Garganta opens up with Wonderweiss and a creature Gin calls Hooleer later on. seeing it Captain Komamura says that it was the same eye he saw when Aizen was estracted from the Soul Society by the Menos.

But what is Hooleer? it doesn't have a Hollow's Mask or any fragments of one nor does it have a hole on it's body (at least from what i have seen). is it even a Hollow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Hooleer (Fūrā) is a large Hollow in the service of Sōsuke Aizen." This is what say in [bleach wikie](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Hooleer)

**Appearance**

Hooleer has a bulbous body, long tufts of hair on its back, and a single, large eye it is purple inside of the Garganta and yellow outside of it. Its hair is to be the same or a similar color to its skin.It has Gillian masks for fingernails.

Source - [Bleach Wikie](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Hooleer)
[image: Hooler]